# Замена значений в xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Есть xml вида:

```
<Notification>
  <MTYPE>Notification</MTYPE>
  <PODATE>2018-07-11T00:00:00</PODATE>
  <TYPE>1</TYPE>
  <PORPOS>
    <PPSNR>1</PPSNR>
    <EXP>2018-12-31T23:59:59</EXP>
    <QUAN>307,2</QUAN>
    <PUOM>307,2</PUOM>
  </PORPOS>
  <PORPOS>
    <PPSNR>2</PPSNR>
    <EXP>2018-12-31T23:59:59</EXP>
    <QUAN>10,2</QUAN>
    <PUOM>5,2</PUOM>
  </PORPOS>
</Notification>
```

Нужно заменить значения в тегах QUAN и PUOM, поменять запятую на точку.
Про метод `replace value of exp1 with exp2` знаю.  Как вставить в exp2  стандартный SQL Replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @xml xml = '<Notification>
  <MTYPE>Notification</MTYPE>
  <PODATE>2018-07-11T00:00:00</PODATE>
  <TYPE>1</TYPE>
  <PORPOS>
    <PPSNR>1</PPSNR>
    <EXP>2018-12-31T23:59:59</EXP>
    <QUAN>307,2</QUAN>
    <PUOM>307,2</PUOM>
  </PORPOS>
  <PORPOS>
    <PPSNR>2</PPSNR>
    <EXP>2018-12-31T23:59:59</EXP>
    <QUAN>10,2</QUAN>
    <PUOM>5,2</PUOM>
  </PORPOS>
</Notification>'

declare @count int = @xml.value('count(//PORPOS)', 'int');
declare @i int = 1
declare @quan varchar(80)
declare @puom varchar(80)

while @i <= @count
begin
    set @quan = @xml.value('((//QUAN)[sql:variable("@i")]/text())[1]', 'varchar(80)')
    set @quan = replace(@quan, ',', '.')
    set @xml.modify('
        replace value of ((//QUAN)[sql:variable("@i")]/text())[1]
        with sql:variable("@quan")
    ')

    set @puom = @xml.value('((//PUOM)[sql:variable("@i")]/text())[1]', 'varchar(80)')
    set @puom = replace(@puom, ',', '.')
    set @xml.modify('
        replace value of ((//PUOM)[sql:variable("@i")]/text())[1]
        with sql:variable("@puom")
    ')

    set @i += 1
end

select @xml;
```

Простого способа нет.

Сперва получаем общее количество узлов `PORPOS` и делаем по ним цикл.

В цикле получаем значение нужного узла, меняем запятую на точку, затем меняем само значение.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за решение. Сам тоже думал про цикл.

Answer (score 0):

Есть более простой метод, как по мне:

```
SELECT
    mainTable.fst.value('(Notification/MTYPE)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    nodes.setting.value('(PPSNR)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    nodes.setting.value('(EXP)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    replace(nodes.setting.value('(QUAN)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), ',', '.'),
    replace(nodes.setting.value('(PUOM)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), ',', '.')
FROM mainTable
CROSS APPLY mainTable.fst.nodes('Notification/PORPOS/.[1]') nodes(setting)
```

Без циклов проходитесь по всем узлам и последовательно все меняете. Использовал `SELECT` в качестве примера

Comment: Извлекать данные с помощью `cross apply` очень удобно. Но как сделать именно обновление xml в таблице? Вроде как невозможно обновить одну строку более одного раза в одном выражении update. А именно это нужно делать, ведь узлов более одного.