# Изменить значение node в XML во всех строках таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Есть таблица с заполненными в xml значениями

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), xmlColumn xml);  

INSERT INTO #Table VALUES('  
<script>
    <string>00000</string>
    <dup></dup>
    <tabList>
        <tab>
            <id>first</id>
            <name>firstItem</name>
            <inData></inData>
            <inScript></inScript>
            <outData></outData>
            <outScript></outScript>

        </tab>
    </tabList>  
    <tabList>
        <tab>
            <id>second</id>
            <name>secondItem</name>
            <inData></inData>
            <inScript></inScript>
            <outData>Big house</outData>
            <outScript>Big shop</outScript>
        </tab>
    </tabList>
    <tabList>
        <tab>
            <id>third</id>
            <name>thirdItem</name>
            <inData>Big car</inData>
            <inScript>Big bus</inScript>
            <outData>Big house</outData>
            <outScript>Big shop</outScript>
        </tab>
    </tabList>
</script>'), ('  
<script>
    <string>00000</string>
    <dup></dup>
    <tabList>
        <tab>
            <id>first</id>
            <name>firstItem</name>
            <inData></inData>
            <inScript></inScript>
            <outData></outData>
            <outScript></outScript>

        </tab>
    </tabList>  
    <tabList>
        <tab>
            <id>second</id>
            <name>secondItem</name>
            <inData></inData>
            <inScript></inScript>
            <outData>Big house</outData>
            <outScript>Big shop</outScript>
        </tab>
    </tabList>
    <tabList>
        <tab>
            <id>third</id>
            <name>thirdItem</name>
            <inData>Big car</inData>
            <inScript>Big bus</inScript>
            <outData>Big house</outData>
            <outScript>Big shop</outScript>
        </tab>
    </tabList>
</script>');
```

Каким способом можно изменить значения node только inData и inScript (не затрагивая outData,outScript) во всех строках таблицы
Заменив все значения 'Big' на 'Little'

Пытался так:

```
UPDATE t
SET
    t.xmlColumn = xmlColumn.query('
        element script
        {
            for $a in (/script/tabList/tab/*)
            return
                if (local-name($a) = "inData")
                then element inData { text { sql:column("d2.inData") } }
                else if (local-name($a) = "inScript")
                then element inScript { text { sql:column("d2.inScript") } }
                else $a
        }
    ')
FROM
    #Table t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            inData = t.xmlColumn.value('(/script/tabList/tab/inData/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(400)'),
            inScript = t.xmlColumn.value('(/script/tabList/tab/inScript/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(400)')
    ) d
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            inData = REPLACE(d.inData, N'Big', N'Little'),
            inScript = REPLACE(d.inScript, N'Big', N'Little')
    ) d2

    SELECT * FROM #Table
```

Но код выдаёт только те значения, которые были изменены. Необходимо, чтобы в итоге отображалась вся xml-структура, включая ту, что не была изменена.

Также значение нодов в строках таблицы могут меняться.

Comment: Тут возникает вопрос целесообразности такого хранения. XML так в DB не хранят именно из-за подобных сложностей. Рекомендую еще раз проанализировать систему хранения данных. На тему хранения структур в реляционных базах: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/11/datatype-json

Comment: Укажите СУБД. Sql Server?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, всё правильно...думаю что можно циклом перебрать

Comment: Ну? Покажите ваши попытки с циклом. Могу предложить посмотреть [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879697/184217), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/903992/184217).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я делал по второму примеру
но если нодов с таким названием несколько (в примере "collaborator`ов"), то вернётся только тот который менялся.

Comment: Вопрос решён? Если нет, отредактируйте его, - снова откроем.

Answer (score 1):

Использовал XQuery/FLWOR.

Подразумевается, что корневой элемент всегда имеет имя script и в узле tabList всегда есть вложенный tab. Структура и названия других узлов произвольны.

```
update #Table
set xmlColumn = xmlColumn.query('
element script
{       
    for $a in (/script/*)
    return
        if (local-name($a) != "tabList")
        then $a
        else
            element tabList
            {
                element tab
                {
                    for $b in ($a/tab/*)
                    return
                        if (local-name($b) != "inData" and local-name($b) != "inScript")
                        then $b
                        else
                            if (local-name($b) = "inData")
                            then element inData
                            {
                                if (substring($b, 1, 3) = "Big")
                                then concat("Little", substring($b, 4))
                                else string($b)
                            }
                            else element inScript
                            {
                                if (substring($b, 1, 3) = "Big")
                                    then concat("Little", substring($b, 4))
                                    else string($b)
                            }
                }
            }
}')
```

Comment: По сути задача для xslt. Жаль что в t-sql нет встроенных средств для этого.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , а как можно использовать вместо постоянных "Big"/"Little" переменную, если значение будет динамическим

Comment: @dev_code - Не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. Комментарии никто не увидит. Вся информация должна быть в самом вопросе. И почему этой информации сразу не было в вопросе?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, изначально значения нодов менялись через replace и сross apply, что было в принципе понятно. Но возвращаемое значение не было полноценной структурой xml. Последнее решение в скрипте работает. Но если значение нодов могут быть разными в строках, то поменять их с присвоением нового значение не получается, поэтому использую переменную